# Excel VBA - import multiple xlsx worksheets and append to master workbook sheet

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I am trying to import multiple XLSX/XLS sheets into my Master Workbook's "temp" sheet, each workbooks content should be appended after the last entry.

This works well with just one file, but I cannot seem to work out the logic behind looping through all selected workbooks. Also, considering performance and speed, is a wise to open all selected workbooks after they have been selected or should I rather open them after the import of the previous file is done?

Would appreciate your kind help.

EDIT:
To be a bit more precise, the problem with the script is the part where I am supposed to look through all open workbooks. Suggestions anyone?

```
For Each Workbooks In lngCount

    With Workbooks
        .Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=MasterWB.Sheets("temp").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Close False
    End With

Next
```

Full VBA Code:

```
Sub import_XLS()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim lngCount As Long

' speed up by turning screenupdating off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' set workbooks
    Set MasterWB = ActiveWorkbook

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temp")
        .Visible = True
        .Cells.Delete
    End With

' Open the file dialog
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .InitialFileName = ""
        .Title = "Please select the converted User Activity files for import"
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls; *.xlsx", 1
        '.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls", 1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True

        If .Show = -1 Then
             ' Open the files
            For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(lngCount)
            Next lngCount

            Else
                Exit Sub
        End If

    End With

' open selected workbook in read only and copy all cells of worksheet 1

For Each Workbooks In lngCount

    With Workbooks
        .Sheets(1).Cells.Copy Destination:=MasterWB.Sheets("temp").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Close False
    End With

Next

' hide temp sheet, close workbook without saving changes and free memory
    'MasterWB.Sheets("temp").Visible = False
    'wb.Close False
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: did you really got that code working? In my VBE it has some "compiler" errors such as in `For Each Workbooks In lngCount` line where it wouldn't allow you to iterate through anything but collections or arrays. I'd also suggest you to add `Option Explicit` statement at the very beginning of your module so that it'll force you to declare each variable you're using. the little extra work will be rewarded letting you spot and fix every type mismatch

Comment: I actually stated at the very beginning that the "For each workbooks" statement doesnt work, thats why I am here for help :)

Comment: well you may fix and debug your code as per my comments. and finally update it in the code box together with possible issues left

Comment: Thanks, I get it, but again, HOW do I loop through selected workbooks? Its not that I dont know where the error is, its rather that I dont know HOW to go about it the right way and would appreciate if someone could point out an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim wb As Workbook
....

For Each wb In Workbooks
    with wb
        if .name <>MasterWB.Name
        ....    
    end with
Next wb
```

Comment: is there any way to ignore the active workbook (MasterWB)? With this solution, it will also address the currently active workbook as it is also considered "open".

Comment: see edits. and not clear your concern about "currently active workbook": it's the last one opened during the previous `For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count` loop, so it should be one to deal with.